# Changing the direction of Depth First Search

Tags: java, stack, depth-first-search

I was just wondering, is it possible to change the direction of depth first search?  I have to find the path from the starting node to the goal node. Here's how my depth first search result looks like. 0 5 7 8 9 10 6 4 1 3 2 11. The starting node is 0 and my goal node is 1. The path I want is 0 5 4 1. Does direction really matters in depth first search?
Here's my code:

```
public void performIterativeDFS(Graph G, int node, int goal) {
    ArrayBasedStack arrayStack = new ArrayBasedStack();
    arrayStack.push(node);
    visited[node] = true;
    while (!arrayStack.isEmpty()) {
        int n = arrayStack.pop();
        System.out.print(n + " ");
        for (int w : G.adjList(n)) {
            if (!visited[w]) {
                visited[w] = true;
                arrayStack.push(w);
                if (w == goal) {
                    goal = w;
                    System.out.print(" Goal Found: ");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Structure:

```
11 3
2 3
0 3
1 4
5 4
5 7
6 7
7 8
8 9
9 10
0 5
```

Comment: You don't tell us how those nodes are related, or how they could be linked to one another.

Comment: Basically, I have a text file that contains pair of numbers/nodes which shows connection to each other. It is actually an undirected graph so it does not have any weights at all it's just a pair of numbers.

Comment: Be that as it may, your listing of numbers does not indicate to me what that structure is.

Comment: I have post my structure. It is a adjacency list structure.

Comment: Okay, so with *this* file, it doesn't look like you'll ever make it to 1.

Comment: What do you mean? I have clearly mention it in my description that I found the path to the goal. The main question only if I can change the direction of the depth first search when I get to 5 which connected to 4 and 7.

Comment: Ah, I must have misread it.  It's bidirectional.  Give me a moment.

Comment: It's ok.. Do you understand my structure??

Answer (score 1):

DFS randomly selects a direction whenever a choice is possible and continues in that direction, marking previous positions, until it hits a roadblock. I am not sure how and why you would control that direction. However, If you are looking for the shortest path use Breadth first search(BFS) to do that. It will systematically explore nearby nodes before moving ahead and will give you the most optimal path.

Comment: It's not always "random", but I would settle for "indeterminate", especially if the adjacent list were implemented as a set of some kind.

Comment: I Agree, it depends on the adjacency list implementation also I think DFS may not always provide the best results in the situation as described by OP

Comment: @thepiyush13 Are you saying there is a possibility to change the direction using the adjacency list structure? If so, any idea how?

Comment: what I meant was that instead of letting DFS randomly choose a direction , you can use a data structure like priority queue, which assigns higher priority to some nodes, thus while picking a node to explore DFS would pick highest priority node and so on.

Comment: @thepiyush13 Even with undirected graph? Isn't it Breadth First Search uses Queue?

Comment: I agree but there is a small difference, you are not using queue and you are not exploring all the nodes, you are just assigning high priority paths which are more likely to contain the destination node.The problem with this DFS is that even if you give it a fixed direction how would you know that the two nodes have a connected path in that direction?that's why I initially suggested BFS,  If you still want to use DFS than something like path priority has to be there.